# Phonegap InAppBrowser not working in (iOS) - Exception thrown

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am launching an inapp browser from my phonegap app and I get the following exception:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException>
 *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:
 attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
```

The code to launch the inAppBrowser:

```
function loginFromInAppBrowser() {
    var client_id="clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    var state="whatever_you_want";
    var scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only";
    var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" + client_id + "&state=" + state + "&redirect_uri=mypackage:/oauth2callback&scope=" + scope;

    var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {console.log(event.url+event.token);});
    ref.addEventListener('onerror', function() { console.log('error');});
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { console.log('start');});
}
```

In my app I just get a blank screen with the 'done' button on the bottom and says loading.  Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the spaces in the url passed to inAppBrowser().  The URL must be encoded with encodeURI().  This is mentioned in the [phonegap docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html):

url: the URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if you have Unicode characters in your URL.